# Doxygen 1.7.4 with names containing "$$" in ANSI C

Tags: c, linker, doxygen, keil

I'm experiencing a problem with documenting the variables containing the double$ ("$$") in the name. In fact these names are not real variables but rather the Keil Linker-generated constants. The $$ appears to have a special (undocumented?) meaning for the Doxygen parser. If I write the following code

```
extern char SectionA$$Base[];     /** starting address of the section **/
extern char SectionA$$Limit[];    /** end address of the section  **/
```

Doxygen complains about the undocumented variables $$Base and $$Limit, includes it in the documentation with the names where the $$ is prepend by space using weird combinations of bold, link and so on attributes and without any comment. The total quantity of the variables declared this way is 8. Nevertheless the documentation output contains 2 or sometimes 4 of the declarations. So $$ apears to have a big influence I don't understand.

How can I force Doxygen to treat this variables like any other one?

Comment: `Doxygen` is not wrong to be confused, for your code does not conform to standard C.  The `$` character is not permitted in identifiers, unless as an extension.  It is usually wise to avoid relying on extensions, for they can cause you a wide variety of difficulties.  I'd recommend using an underscore (`_`) in place of `$`.

Comment: John, I would never use this kind of naming. But the Linker of Keil follows it's own rules and creates the names like <SectionName>$$Base and <SectionName>$$Limit. In fact, using these names is the only way to check for example whether a specific address is located in a specific section.

Comment: @John Depends which standard C you mean. Maybe not ANSI, but it certainly does conform to standard C99 - it's just not necessarily portable between different C99 implementations, much like the size of an `int`, the signedness of `char`, signed integer overflow, and other swathes of the language ;) (extreme pedantry, I know, but hey...)

Comment: @Notlikethat, you are correct that the current standard (C2011, but also previously C99) permits identifiers to contain "other implementation-defined characters", whereas ANSI C, which I interpret to mean C89, does not.  It would not be quite right to call support for such characters an extension, and I would have been more correct with respect to the current standard to say that the OP's code does not *strictly* conform.  Still, Doxygen provides its own partial implementation of C, so portability and strict conformance considerations are relevant.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, `Doxygen` has no command or configuration option for accepting invalid identifiers.  It does, however, support filtering input files prior to processing them.  You could perhaps use that to alter the offending declarations, or to remove them from among those passed on to Doxygen.  See the `INPUT_FILTER`, `FILTER_PATTERNS`, and related configuration options.

Alternatively, you could put the offending declarations in a separate header, and omit that header from Doxygen processing (`EXCLUDE` and or `EXCLUDE_PATTERNS` can help).

I don't see a way to use Doxygen to actually generate documentation for these identifiers.